# Limit of product of functions with one real limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$ where $L > 0$, and that $\lim_{x \to c}g(x) = \infty$. Show that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)g(x) = \infty$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Bungo I was trying to come up with an inequality that I could manipulate to show that the limit of the product is great than M for any M > 0 which would suffice as a proof but I can't set it up.

Comment: That sounds like a good start. Let $M > 0$. We want to show that for $x$ sufficiently close to $c$, we have $f(x)g(x) > M$. One way to see this is to show that if $x$ is close enough to $c$, then $f(x) > L/2$, and $g(x) > 2M/L$, so the product satisfies $f(x)g(x) > (L/2)(2M/L) = M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, one has that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $$0<|x-c|<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon \Longleftrightarrow -\varepsilon + L<f(x)<\varepsilon+L$$ and, for every $M>0$ there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that $$0<|x-c|<\delta_2 \implies |g(x)|>M.$$ If we choose $\delta:=\min\{ \delta_1,\delta_2 \}$ then if $0<|x-c|<\delta$, for $\varepsilon \in (0,L)$, we have $$|f(x)g(x)|\geq f(x)g(x)>Mf(x)>M(-\varepsilon +L),$$ and since $M>0$ and $L-\varepsilon>0$ are arbitrary, setting $M':=M(L-\varepsilon)$ we arrive at $|f(x)g(x)|>M'$ whenever $0<|x-c|<\delta$. This finishes the proof.